# Proving that $f(z) = \frac{1}{2} \left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right)$ is biholomorph on a certain set

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \backslash \{0\} \to \mathbb{C}$ be given by

$$f(z) := \frac{1}{2} \left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right)$$

I first want to find the image of the set $H = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < 1, Im(z) > 0\}$ (the open upper half of the unit circle) regarding $f$.

Next, I want to show that $f$ sends $H$ biholomorph onto $f(H)$. Finally, I want to figure out the inverse mapping $f^{-1}$, as defined on $f(H)$.

My attempt so far: I've noticed that $f(z) = f(\frac{1}{z})$. As $lim_{t \downarrow 0} |f(t i)| = \infty $, the values $f$ takes on $H$ can become "very large" regarding their absolute value, hence, $f(H)$ is unbounded. On the other hand, we have that $i$ is a root of $f$ (and, besides $-i$, the only root of it). I therefore suspect that $f(H)$ might be something like the lower half of the complex plane $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: Im(z) < 0\}$ or an unbounded subset of it? (Because $Im(f(z)) < 0 \space \forall z: 1 > Im(z) > 0$ if I'm not mistaken; therefore, it can only be a subset of the lower half of $\mathbb{C}$.) I don't really know how to cleverly continue from there?

I know that in order to show biholomorphy, I would need to show that $f^{-1}$ is also holomorph; hence, it would be useful to first figure out $f^{-1}$ regarding $f(H)$. Maybe, it's already visible then on why $f^{-1}$ is holomorph. So my main problem is to figure out $f(H)$, and determine $f^{-1}$.

EDIT: Actually, since $f(z) = f(\frac{1}{z})$, does that mean that $f(\{z \in \mathbb{C}: Im(z) < 0\} \backslash H) = f(H)$, or am I mistaken there? I'm not sure though how that might help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Write 
$$ 
 f(z) = \frac{1}{2} \left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right) = \frac{\left( \frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)^2 + 1}{\left( \frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)^2 - 1}
 = T_2(S(T_1(z))
$$
as the concatenation of three "simple" mappings:
$$
 T_1(z) = \frac{1+z}{1-z}, S(z) = z^2, T_2(z) = \frac{z+1}{z-1}
$$

Use the basic properties of [Möbiustransformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation)
to conclude
that $T_1$ is a biholomorphic mapping from $H$ to the first quadrant.
Now consider $S$ restricted to the first quadrant. Is it one-to-one?
What is the image? Finally determine the image under $T_2$ which
is again a Möbiustransformation.

Each of the three mappings can be inverted easily, that allows you
to compute $f^{-1}$.

> I therefore suspect that $f(H)$
>    might be something like the lower half of the complex plane ...

Correct!

> Actually, since $f(z) = f(\frac{1}{z})$, does that mean that ...

$z \to 1/z$ maps $H$ to $G := \{ z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| > 1, \text{Im}(z) < 0\}$,
therefore $f(H) = f(G)$.

Comment: Thanks,  that helped a lot. The only thing I'm still having trouble with, is on how to evaluate the images of H and $S(T_1(H))$ regarding $T_1$ and $T_2$? I haven't worked with Möbiustransformations before. Which properties of them can help me justify the respective image sets?

Comment: @moran: They are bijective mappings of the extended complex plane onto itself, lines and circles are mapped to lines and circles, angles are preserved, and they are uniquely identified by the image of three points. – For example, from $T_1(-1) = 0$, $T_1(1) = \infty$, $T_1(i) = i$ it follows that $T_1$ maps the unit circle to the imaginary axis.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Muskhelishvili transform, for the special case $R=1/2$. It maps circles into circles and ellipses and vice versa.

To see examples of it in action, parametrize an open sub-cover of the domain $H$ in question, as:

$$H_1=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\colon z=(\rho-\epsilon)\cdot\exp(\theta i), 0\lt \theta\lt\pi\}$$

$$H_2=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\colon z=r\cdot\exp(0 i)+\epsilon\cdot i, -\rho+\epsilon\lt r\lt\rho-\epsilon\}$$

It's holomorphic,so just look at the subcover under the map, for various values of $\rho$, below in the graphs.

Its inverse is gotten by solving the following equation for $z$:

$$w=\frac{1}{2}\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)$$

which gives for $f^{-1}$:

$$z=w\pm\sqrt{w^2-1}$$

Therefore the inverse has two branches and two branch points at $f^{-1}(z_c)$, with:

$$z_c=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\colon \frac{df(z)}{dz}=0\}=\{-1,1\}$$

Hence the two branches of $f^{-1}$ can be joined together through only a branch cut between -1 and 1, making the inverse holomorphic everywhere away from this branch cut.

Some Maple code to help a bit:

```
restart;
with(plots);
eps := 0.5e-1;
f := proc (z) options operator, arrow; (1/2)*z+(1/2)/z end proc;
z := proc (rho, theta) options operator, arrow; rho*exp(I*theta) end proc;
rho := 1;
p1 := complexplot(z(rho-eps, theta), theta = 0 .. Pi, scaling = constrained, color = red);
p2 := complexplot(z(r, 0)+I*eps, r = -rho+eps .. rho-eps, scaling = constrained, color = red);
p3 := complexplot(f(z(rho-eps, theta)), theta = 0 .. Pi, scaling = constrained, color = blue);
p4 := complexplot(f(z(r, 0)+I*eps), r = -rho+eps .. rho-eps, scaling = constrained, color = blue);
display(p1, p2, p3, p4);
```

Graphs for $\rho=1$, $\rho=1/2$ and $\rho=2$ follow:

[image]
[image]
[image]