# Showing a Function is a Conformal Isomorphism

Tags: complex-analysis

I have what seems like it should be a fairly basic question, but I'm not sure how to address! I want to show that the function $g: H = \mathbb{H}\setminus\bar{\mathbb{D}} \to \mathbb{C}$ given by
$$g(z) = z + 1/z$$
defines a conformal isomorphism into $\mathbb{H}$. ($\mathbb{H}$ is the (open) upper half plane and $\mathbb{D}$ is the (open) unit disc, as usual.)

A few of the bits are easy, in particular that the range is $\mathbb{H}$, that $g$ maps the Martin boundary $\delta H = (\partial \mathbb{D} \cap \mathbb{H}) \cup (\mathbb{R} \setminus (-1,1))$ to the Martin boundary $\delta \mathbb{H} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ and that $g$ is conformal. Further, showing surjectivity is pretty basic. I'm stuck on showing that $g$ injective, and hence a bijection, and hence an isomorphism.

Any assistance would be most appreciated! :)

For those who are wondering about the motivation of this question, $g$ is the mapping-out function for the compact $\mathbb{H}$-hull $\mathbb{H}\cap\bar{\mathbb{D}}$ -- at least, so I'm proving!

Comment: Step 1), $g$ is a rational function of order (or degree) $2$, so every $w\in \widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ has exactly two preimages, counting multiplicity. Step 2), $g(1/z) = g(z)$.

Comment: Possibly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1619927/proving-that-fz-frac12-leftz-frac1z-right-is-biholomorph-on.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, that does help to see. Not exactly the same, but definitely related.

Comment: @DanielFischer The first step is what was throwing me: I thought that every point should have two preimages. However, I didn't think about the fact that $g(z) = g(1/z)$, and thus (off the boundary) exactly one will have $|z_1| > 1$ and the other $|z_2| < 1$. [continued]

Comment: Surjectivity isn't quite as obvious as I originally assumed: I need to show that the preimage is in $H$; there's clearly one (two, in fact) in $\mathbb{C}$. I just need to do a bit of bookkeeping to make sure that the one modulus greater than $1$ is in the upper half, not the lower half! Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Surjectivity is also easy, if you keep the whole sphere in mind. What is $g(\overline{z})$?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb H\setminus\overline{\mathbb D}$? Otherwise $g(i) = 0$, which is not an element of $\mathbb H$ and the claim is obviously false. If you mean $\mathbb H\setminus\overline{\mathbb D}$, then injectivity is actually easy to see. $g(z) = g(w)$ is equivalent to $(z-w)(1-\frac 1 {zw}) = 0$. Hence, either $z = w$ or $w = 1/z$ (where in this case $|w| = 1/|z| < 1$. Contradiction!).

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah yes, $g(\overline{z}) = \overline{g(z)}$. I have it sorted now thanks to your hint. :) -- Also, thanks for giving advice, not just telling me the answer! Now if something similar comes up again, I'll have a better idea of how to attack it, instead of just knowing one result!

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Yes, I did mean $H$ to be a simply connected domain (as is standard for considering compact $\mathbb{H}$-hulls). Thanks to Daniel Fischer's hint, I was able to deduce exactly what you've written. :)

Comment: Great. Wanna wrap it up and write an answer?

Comment: @Smiley Sam That does not answer my question, right? If you really mean $\mathbb H\setminus\mathbb D$ then your function does not map into $\mathbb H$ (as you write) as my simple example above shows. So, the claim is false.

Comment: @DanielFischer Good shout, will do shortly. Thanks again :)

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp By "yes", I meant "yes I mean your correction". What I had written before $H$ wasn't a domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows from these observations (thank you Daniel Fischer). (Don't upvote this answer: upvote Daniel Fischer's comments!)

- $g(z) = g(1/z)$, so of the two solutions obtained from $g(z) = w$, with $|w| \neq 1$, one lies inside $\mathbb{D}$ and the other outside.
- $g(\overline{z}) = \overline{g(z)}$; in fact, this is a general principle for the mapping out function of a compact $\mathbb{H}$-hull.